# C# Why wouldn't it display the values I set in the List?

Tags: c#, list, class, inheritance, bank

Hi I really need help on this inheritance project. I need my form to display all the data in each label when the user selected a value in the combobox. I got all the data declared in the list but I dont know why the label still shows ZEROs when I select value.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void accountNumComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (accountNumComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            SavingsAccount savings = new SavingsAccount();
            ownerIdLabel.Text = savings.OwnerId;
            balanceLabel.Text = savings.Balance.ToString("c");
            interestLabel.Text = (string.Format("{0}%", savings.Interest));
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<SavingsAccount> savings = new List<SavingsAccount>();

        SavingsAccount savings1 = new SavingsAccount();
        savings1.OwnerId = "0001";
        savings1.AccountNumber = "31-1000";
        savings1.Balance = 100m;
        savings1.Interest = 0.01;

        SavingsAccount savings2 = new SavingsAccount();
        savings2.OwnerId = "0002";
        savings2.AccountNumber = "31-1001";
        savings2.Balance = 1000m;
        savings2.Interest = 0.0125;
```

And here is my SavingsAccount class

```
 class SavingsAccount : BankAccount
{
    //field
    private double _interest;

    //constructor
    public SavingsAccount(string ownerID, string acctNumber, decimal balance, double interest)
        : base(ownerID, acctNumber, balance)
    {
        _interest = interest;
    }
    //interest property
    public double Interest
    {
        get { return _interest; }
        set { _interest = value; }
    }
    public SavingsAccount()
    {

    }
}
```

I'll appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: The variables in your `Form1_Load` and `accountNumComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` have no relationship to each other.

Comment: This is a fundamental misunderstanding and is going to be too broad to explain in an answer. The long and short is that the `savings` variable you use in the form load event is in no way related to the one in your index changed event just because they have the same name. You also don't show adding anything to the list.

Comment: You've missed a whole lot of code from the `Form1_Load` method that might be helpful. The crux of the issue is that you need to keep a reference to the `savings` list that you created, and re-use the elements of the list - calling `new SavingsAccount()` doesn't re-use the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Although you declare values in the code below, it doesn't appear that you are actually using it.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<SavingsAccount> savings = new List<SavingsAccount>();

    SavingsAccount savings1 = new SavingsAccount();
    savings1.OwnerId = "0001";
    savings1.AccountNumber = "31-1000";
```

When you write the code below, you're creating a new localized object inside of the event; you're not using the values you tried to give it before:

```
 private void accountNumComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (accountNumComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        SavingsAccount savings = new SavingsAccount();
        ownerIdLabel.Text = savings.OwnerId;
        balanceLabel.Text = savings.Balance.ToString("c");
```

My suggestion would be to move this piece of code: `List<SavingsAccount> savings = new List<SavingsAccount>();`just underneath of your `private double _interest` declaration. That would make it accessible by your other methods and events.

Comment: Thank you but it didn't seem to work for me. should I create a new method for this list since form_load and the selectedindex isn't related with each other? Or any way I can make use of the values I declared? I'm really lost at this one